# How to access variables in OOP

Tags: php, mysql, oop, pdo

I am trying to find a way to get the variable called `$connect` to run but don't know how.

Filename: */engine/init.php*

```
class Engine {
    function MySQL() {
        $connect = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name;charset=$db_char", $db_user, $db_pass);
    }
}
```

Filename: */inc/database.php*

```
require 'engine/init.php;
$engine = new Engine;
$conn = $engine->MySQL;
// Activate $connect variable
```

If it's not clear, please request for more info.

Thanks,
CrAzYz_

Comment: First the `MySQL()` wont work because you have not defined `$db_host,..` at this point. Then if you want to get $connect do `return $connect;` But this is a bad example for a class mapper. Tip: Bind to `$this->connect=connet()` and reuse it.

Comment: The variable needs to be class-level, not method-level: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php  Or are you trying to *return* the variable instead?  It's not really clear from the usage...

Comment: frankly, this code makes no sense. you should explain what you want to do here and why. especially what is Engine and why do you think in needs a mysql method

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions Yes, I know. I did not type in the variables because that would cause a database credentials leak. Your answer should have the fix, trying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to update the class to access members outside.
You have several options to do it.

1: store the connection in a `public` property

```
class Engine {
    public $connection;

    public function MySQL() {
        $this->connection = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name;charset=$db_char",$db_user, $db_pass);
    }
}
```

This way you can retrieve it by

```
$engine = new Engine();
$engine->MySQL();
$conn = $engine->connection;
```

2: Make the function return the connection

```
class Engine {
    public function MySQL() {
        return new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name;charset=$db_char",$db_user, $db_pass);
    }
}
```

This way your example will work (if you use Mysql as a function):

```
$engine = new Engine();
$conn = $engine->MySQL();
```

3: A more complicated but generally better aproach:

```
class Engine {
    protected $connection;

    public function __construct($db_host, $db_name, $db_user, $db_pass $db_char = "utf-8") {
        $this->connection = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name;charset=$db_char",$db_user, $db_pass);
    }

    public function MySQL() {
        if ( !$this->connection instanceof PDO ) {
            throw new Exception("Connection is not set up");
        }

        return $this->connection;
    }
}
```

This would work almost as you wanted, except you cant access the connection directly (its protected), but only through the MySql function. This way if you forgot to init the connection an exception is thrown.

```
$engine = new Engine("localhost", "db_name", "user", "pass");
$conn   = $engine->MySQL();  // you don't even need to save the connection to a local variable, because the function only references the connection and won't start a new one
```

Footnote:
If you had to as this kind of question you should probably look up and learn more about OOP. For php this is a start: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Answer (score 0):

About to run off so this is a little quickly done.

```
class Engine
{
    public $db;

    public function connect($host, $database, $charset, $user, $pass) 
    {
        $this->db = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database;charset=$charset", $user, $pass);
    }
}
```

First of we have your `Engine` class that you want to create, we've created a property named `db` on the class that we can access with `->db`. We also have a method called `connect` which we pass our database variables into so that PDO can connect to our database.

Now we pass in our database credentials to our `connect` method, in a production environment I really would advise against hard coding these and instead use something like environment variables.

```
$engine = new Engine();
$engine->connect('127.0.0.1', 'example_database', 'UTF-8', 'root', 'root');
```

We can then use our newly initiated `PDO` connection like so:

```
$statement = $engine->db->query('SELECT * FROM some_table');
$result    = $statement->execute();
```

That should at least give you a starting point, there are other ways to go about this but I didn't want to stray too far from your original code.

Also if anyone spots anything wrong, let me know and i'll update it when I'm back in, need to run off in a sec.